# Post-Service Pack 1, Broken Web Applications (User Profile Sync)

Tags: upgrade, user-profile-service, web-application

I had a clean environment prior to installing service pack 1 and the June CUs. User Profile Sync is up and running, and synchronizing, but all web applications are throwing a SharePoint error. Digging into the logs, we're getting "Exception occurred while connecting to WCF endpoint" claiming the connection request to ProfilePropertyService.svc exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:20. If I hit ProfilePropertyService.svc manually I get "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error."

I have tried blowing away UPS, rebooting, rebuilding UPS and rebooting, and that did not resolve the issue. All services are started, and all application pools are online.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Update - Looks like it is unique to a single web front end.  Removed it from the load balancing and the farm functions normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this wasn't a UPS specific issue; one of the web front ends essentially bricked itself as part of the upgrade. Detaching it from the farm and re-adding it didn't solve the issue; we actually ended up rebuilding the box.

Answer (score 1):

We've run into a couple of problems with the User Profiles after SP1 and June CU.  While they may not be exactly the problem you are encountering, they are something to check to ensure there are no problems from these as well.

1st: FIM's configuration file is changed to use .net 4.0.  This doesn't work, details are in this article [by Todd Carter](http://todd-carter.com/post/2011/07/01/The-User-Profile-Service-Heats-up-With-a-June-CU-Regression.aspx).

2nd: User Profile photos can only be updated by the user themselves -- NOT User profile Admins.  Details in this article [by Trevor Seward](http://sharepoint.nauplius.net/2011/07/user-profile-administrators-can-no.html).

I hope one (or both) of those articles will save you from the late nights my co-worker went thru before finding them.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to a change in the service accounts. Is it possible that there was a manual change to the service accounts through IIS Manager that was reset to the configured account when the configuration manager was run after the service pack installation?

Please refer to [Spencer Harbar's User Profile Sync Guide](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx) for the proper service account roles and permissions if you haven't already.